# libGDX rotate about object

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

In my 3d application I wish to have an object (a tree, for example), and my camera to look at this object. Then, I want the camera to rotate about the object, in a circle, while looking at the tree the whole time. Imagine walking around a tree, while constantly changing your angle so that you are still looking at it. I know this requires both rotation of my camera, and translation of my camera, but the math is far beyond the level I have been taught in schooling thusfar. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
[image: rotationexample]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way with very simple math. First, you need a constant for the distance the camera is from the center of the tree (the radius of the circle path it travels on). Also, you need some variable to track it's angle around the circle.

```
static final float CAM_PATH_RADIUS = 5f;
static final float CAM_HEIGHT = 2f;
float camPathAngle = 0;
```

Now you can change the `camPathAngle` to anything you want from 0 to 360 degrees. 0 degrees corresponds with the location on the circle that is in the same direction as the world's X-axis from the tree's center.

On each frame, after you've update `camPathAngle`, you can do this to update the camera position.

```
void updateTreeCamera(){
    Vector3 camPosition = camera.getPosition();
    camPosition.set(CAM_PATH_RADIUS, CAM_HEIGHT, 0); //Move camera to default location on circle centered at origin
    camPosition.rotate(Vector3.Y, camPathAngle); //Rotate the position to the angle you want. Rotating this vector about the Y axis is like walking along the circle in a counter-clockwise direction.
    camPosition.add(treeCenterPosition); //translate the circle from origin to tree center
    camera.up.set(Vector3.Y); //Make sure camera is still upright, in case a previous calculation caused it to roll or pitch
    camera.lookAt(treeCenterPosition);
    camera.update(); //Register the changes to the camera position and direction
}
```

I did it like that for the sake of commenting it. It's actually shorter than the above if you chain commands:

```
void updateTreeCamera(){
    camera.getPosition().set(CAM_PATH_RADIUS, CAM_HEIGHT, 0)
        .rotate(Vector3.Y, camPathAngle).add(treeCenterPosition);
    camera.up.set(Vector3.Y); 
    camera.lookAt(treeCenterPosition);
    camera.update();
}
```